# Does Delphi offer an event handler for form creation notifications?

Tags: delphi, forms, dynamic, aop

Does Delphi provide some kind of event or hook for form creation (or more generally, form lifecycle events)?

So that if somewhere in the code a form is created and shown (modal or non-modal, dynamically or in the usual app starup stage), Delphi calls an event handler which allows to log / analyse / modify the form before it is shown?

I know there are options which involve introducing a base form class or a custom form creation procedure, but for existing applications which already have many forms it would be 'nice to have' a non-intrusive option to add something similar to cross-cutting concerns in Aspect oriented programming (AOP).

For example, if I had some code for usage statistics tracking which injects additional event handlers, I could simply add this functionality for every form, developers would not have to change the application code, only add code similar to this

```
...
   Application.OnNewForm := MyNewFormCreated;
...

procedure TMyApp.MyNewFormCreated(Sender: TCustomForm);
begin
  // iterate over components and do other stuff with the new form
  ...
end;
```

Comment: There's nothing built in. The best solution is to have a common base class.

Comment: @David: Yes, that is probably the best solution. Please make that an answer.

Comment: @Andreas It's not an answer because @mjn says that common base class is not what is wanted.

Comment: @David, oh, I'm sorry, I missed that.

Comment: You may find `TVirtualMethodInterceptor` in the Rtti unit of the most recent release interesting.

Comment: @Barry Hmm, I'm still on 2010 so not familiar with that but it does sound like just what @mjn needs

Comment: @Barry TVirtualMethodInterceptor has some important limitations: 1. It is RTTI based and it doesn't work for private/protected methods. 2. It is based on replacement of virtual methods table, so it works for virtual methods only (doesn't work for dynamic/static...).

Comment: @AndreiGalatyn I'm aware of the limitations - I wrote it :) - I only mentioned it because it may be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest option I can think of at the moment that could fit your need is the  `Screen.OnActiveFormChange` event that is triggered every time the current active form changes.  But that might be too late in the process for your needs.

Comment: But what about 'too often'? This will fire every time you change the active form. For instance, if you only have two forms in the lifetime of the entire application, but you switch between those 761 times, then the event will fire about 761 times...

Comment: Solved with a `TListOfKnownForms`

Comment: @mjn Are you sure you implemented TListOfKnownForms correctly? How do you identify instances of forms (keeping of pointers is not a solution, if you create-destroy-create the form, second instance may be in the same place in memory as first one)?

Answer (score 5):

At runtime, you may override the `TCustomForm.DoCreate` and `TCustomFrame.Create` methods, as such:

```
type
  THookedForm = class(TCustomForm)
    procedure HookedDoCreate;
  end;

  THookedFrame = class(TCustomFrame)
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

var
  OriginalForm, OriginalFrame: TPatchCode;

procedure PatchCreate;
begin
  if OriginalForm[0]<>0 then
    exit; // patch once
  RedirectCode(@THookedForm.DoCreate,@THookedForm.HookedDoCreate,@OriginalForm);
  RedirectCode(@THookedFrame.Create,@THookedFrame.Create,@OriginalFrame);
end;


// hook logic was inspired from GetText()

{ THookedForm }

procedure THookedForm.HookedDoCreate;
// translate form contents just before an OnCreate handler would be called
begin
  try
  try
    if Language<>nil then begin
      DisableAlign;
      DisableAutoRange;
      try
        Language.FormTranslateOne(self); // translate form
      finally
        EnableAlign;
        EnableAutoRange;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    RedirectCodeRestore(@THookedForm.DoCreate,OriginalForm); // disable Hook
    try
      DoCreate;  // call normal DoCreate event
    finally
      RedirectCode(@THookedForm.DoCreate,@THookedForm.HookedDoCreate);
    end;
  end;
  except
    on Exception do; // ignore all raised exception
  end;
end;

{ THookedFrame }

constructor THookedFrame.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
// translate frame contents just after constructor has been called
begin
  RedirectCodeRestore(@THookedFrame.Create,OriginalFrame); // disable Hook
  try
    inherited Create(AOwner); // call normal constructor
  finally
    RedirectCode(@THookedFrame.Create,@THookedFrame.Create);
  end;
  if Language=nil then exit;
  DisableAlign;
  DisableAutoRange;
  try
    Language.FormTranslateOne(self); // translate frame
  finally
    EnableAlign;
    EnableAutoRange;
  end;
end;


....

initialization
  PatchCreate;
```

Therefore, your own `DoCreate` event will be called each time a TForm instance is created.

This code is extracted from [mORMoti18n.pas](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot/blob/master/SQLite3/mORMoti18n.pas) and you can find the patch routines (for Windows and Linux/BSD) in [SynCommons.pas](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot/blob/master/SynCommons.pas).

Comment: What is a `TPatchEvent`? I suppose it is [this](http://synopse.info/fossil/artifact?name=56e578b8fc9105b44be2562c63f829028f11bc16) record.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez: Your code won't work.  Invoke `DoCreate` in `THookedForm.HookedDoCreate` will call `THookedForm.HookedDoCreate` again and it will repeat calling DoCreate endlessly till the stack overflow.

Comment: @ChauCheeYang This code works on production since years. There is no infinite loop here. ;)

Comment: @Arnaud Just tried with XE6 (Win x32 platform). As Chau mentioned there is infinite loop and it fails with StackOverflow (that's funny) error.

Comment: @Arnaud One more problem in your code - conversion of Pointer to Integer is not correct for x64 platform and under some conditions may lead to crash.

Comment: There are a couple of problems with this solution. As mentioned, this code will result in an infinite loop. Also, you are leaving the memory unprotected so other, perhaps nefarious, processes can also change the memory.

Comment: @Graymatter You are right: there was a problem when I copied & pasted the code. I've updated the latest working version, and made explicit links to the original files, which works correctly - and don't leave the memory unprotected.

Answer (score 3):

```
// Arnaud Bouchez provided great code, but he cut some important pieces of own code.
// And what is more important - he didn't try to run it even once before posting :)
// There is correct unit (copy-pasted from another project & tested with XE6/Win.x32)
// It works for Windows x32 and x64 platforms.

unit HookCreateFrm;

interface

implementation

uses
  Windows, Classes, Forms, IdGlobal, SysUtils;

type
  THookedForm = class(TCustomForm)
    procedure HookedDoCreate;
  end;

  THookedFrame = class(TCustomFrame)
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

  PPatchEvent = ^TPatchEvent;
  // asm opcode hack to patch an existing routine
  TPatchEvent = packed record
    Jump: byte;
    Offset: integer;
  end;

var
  PatchForm, OriginalForm: TPatchEvent;
  PatchPositionForm: PPatchEvent = nil;
  PatchFrame, OriginalFrame: TPatchEvent;
  PatchPositionFrame: PPatchEvent = nil;

procedure PatchCreate;
var ov: cardinal;
begin
  // hook TForm:
  PatchPositionForm := PPatchEvent(@THookedForm.DoCreate);
  OriginalForm := PatchPositionForm^;
  PatchForm.Jump := $E9; // Jmp opcode
  PatchForm.Offset := PByte(@THookedForm.HookedDoCreate)-PByte(PatchPositionForm)-5;
  if not VirtualProtect(PatchPositionForm, 5, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, @ov) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  PatchPositionForm^ := PatchForm; // enable Hook
  // hook TFrame:
  PatchPositionFrame := PPatchEvent(@TCustomFrame.Create);
  OriginalFrame := PatchPositionFrame^;
  PatchFrame.Jump := $E9; // Jmp opcode
  PatchFrame.Offset := PByte(@THookedFrame.Create)-PByte(PatchPositionFrame)-5;
  if not VirtualProtect(PatchPositionFrame, 5, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, @ov) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  PatchPositionFrame^ := PatchFrame; // enable Hook
end;

// hook logic was inspired from GetText()

{ THookedForm }

procedure THookedForm.HookedDoCreate;
begin

  // do what you want before original DoCreate

  PatchPositionForm^ := OriginalForm;
  try
    DoCreate;
  finally
    PatchPositionForm^ := PatchForm;
  end;

  // do what you want after original DoCreate

end;

{ THookedFrame }

constructor THookedFrame.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin

  // do what you want before original DoCreate

  PatchPositionFrame^ := OriginalFrame;
  try
    inherited Create(AOwner);
  finally
    PatchPositionFrame^ := PatchFrame;
  end;

  // do what you want after original Create

end;

initialization
  PatchCreate;

end.
```

Answer (score -1):

If a common superclass based implementation is not an option, this is my wouldbe better too late than never answer:-)

- use a **notification framework**.

[Erik Sasse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2089/erick-sasse)'s `Notification Service` project on Bitbucket is promising. You can get it [here](https://bitbucket.org/esasse/notificationservice). It's based on *TNotify*.

Comment: Common class is not an option because it requires changes in all existing forms of all existing applications. I can't see how suggested list of registered event handlers may help, you have to change every form (of every application) in order to deliver the message from the form (when it is created) to the framework.